# PHP array with Paypal response Array

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I have been having an issue trying to get the value of one field from a Paypal response array. I have been working on it for hours and can not figure it out.

I want the value of $related_resources->sale->id, however I tried

```
$resource_id = $related_resources->sale->id;
```

AND

```
foreach ($related_resources as $related_resource) {
$resource_id = $related_resource->sale-id;
}
```

and neither have worked. Hopefully someone will be able to help me out and save me from this headache.

```
"related_resources": [ { "sale": { "id": "000000000000", "state": 
"completed", "amount": { "total": "0.01", "currency": "USD", "details": { 
"subtotal": "0.01" } }, "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER", 
"protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE", "protection_eligibility_type": 
"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE", 
"transaction_fee": { "value": "0.01", "currency": "USD" }, "receipt_id": 
"00000000000", "parent_payment": "PAY-000000000000000", "create_time": 
"2017-04-28T14:59:05Z", "update_time": "2017-04-28T14:59:05Z"...
```

Comment: You're using a minus sign instead of an arrow between "sale" and "id".

Comment: That was a typo on the end. Sorry about that. Even when using the correct arrow, it still does not yield the desired result.

Comment: Hmmm, then something doesn't seem right.  The second one should have worked.  What do you get when you `var_dump` the response?

Comment: I have tweaked it again and it works now. Thank a lot!